# Lower bound for the fractional Sobolev norm of the Hermites function

Tags: integration, lower-bounds, hermite-polynomials

For $r \in (0, 2)$, I am interested in a lower bound for the quantity :

$$I_r(n) := \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f_n(x)|^2 |x|^{r} dx$$
where $f_n(x) = (-1)^n (\sqrt{\pi} n! 2^n)^{-1/2} e^{x^2/2} \dfrac{d^n}{dx^n} e^{-x^2}$ is the n-th Hermite function.

Using Holder and the closed forms of $I_0(n)$ and $I_2(n)$, I can obtain an upper bound, for $r \in (0,2)$, $I_r(n) \leq C_r n^{r/2}$ with $C_r > 0$.

Concerning a lower bound, I was only able to prove that $I_n(r) \geq C_r$ by spliting the integral over $[-\mu, \mu]$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus[-\mu, \mu]$, with a good choice of $\mu$. But, numerical simulations suggest that $I_n(r) \geq C_r n^{r_0/2}$ with $r_0$ close to $r$.

I have some hope that $I_r(n)$ has been studied somewhere. First of all, a lower bound $I_r(n)$ can be deduced from $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |\widehat{f_n}(x)|^2(1 + |x|^2)^{r/2} dx$, the fractional sobolev norm of $f_n$. Moreover, $I_r(n)$ can be seen as the fractional moment $r$ of $|X|$ where $X$ is a random variable with density $|f_n(x)|^2$.

Do you have any reference, or hint ?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the gazillion of known (and quite sharp) asymptotics for the Hermite functions and integrating them? Good start would be the respective wikipedia article